# How to strip all characters from a string except for numbers, space and +

Tags: java, regex

How to strip all characters from a string except for numbers, space and +?
What is the regex for that?

I want to use

```
String regex = ???
String string = previousString.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

but I dont know how to generate a regex that will only keep 0-9, space and +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regex = "[^\\d\\s\\+]"
```

`^`: not, negate
`d`: number
`s`: space
`+`: you know :)

Comment: Thank you! I will accept as soon as I can. In the meantime, I will test this :)